# Turn off bold font in heading for a single symbol

Tags: fonts, sectioning, bold

The headings commands (`\section`, `\subsection`, etc.) put their text argument in a bold font. I don't want to change that. But I sometimes need to put specific symbols (e.g. phonetic symbols) inside a heading, and these should not appear in a bold font. How can I "turn off" the bold font for a single character within a heading, and let it appear as defined (in the MWE below as an italicized character)? In the MWE example, the character U+01AB doesn't exist in the bold font, so it doesn't appear in the heading at all.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont
    [
        Path = C:/Windows/Fonts/,
        Extension = .ttf,
        UprightFont = Diauni,
        BoldFont = Diaunife,
        ItalicFont = Diauniku,
    ]{dialektuni}
\newcommand{\twithpalhook}{\textit{\char"01AB}}
\begin{document}
\section{I would like the symbol {\twithpalhook} to appear as defined}
The symbol is \twithpalhook.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\textmd{<symbol not in bold>}` or `{\mdseries <symbol not in bold>}`?

Comment: Could you turn that into an answer?

Comment: Define your command from the beginning as `\newcommand{\twithpalhook}{{\normalfont\textit{a}}}` or `\newcommand{\twithpalhook}{{\normalfont\mdseries\textit{a}}}`.

Comment: @Gonzalo: That's a good solution. In my specific case, symbols like these are used 99.9% of the time in paragraphs with a normal font, so it's probably a bit of an overkill to redefine the 50-60 symbols I have defined in this way. But your solution is otherwise spot on.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel An answer?

Answer (score 4):

Use `\normalfont`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\section{This symbol {\normalfont{¿}} is not bold, but this one ¿ is}
\end{document}
```

[image]